# Custom Imageview for irregular shape of drawable or image

Tags: android, imageview, touch

[image]
This is original images and combine from 29 pieces of other small images and final result like this.

For example, when I click the particular area,the small piece will change to another colour.

[image]
Is there any solution that I can detect the particular area touch and know which piece of image should change?

Comment: So you mean each part is an image??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yup, each part is an small piece of image for example, 4 wheels.

Comment: have you tried onclicklistener in the imageview?

Comment: How could you combine each shape into one piece, just use many ImageView? or original image was an entirety picture? I believe it very complicated.

Comment: @VinceStyling finding way either use canvas combine bitmap or use many imageviews which are irregular shape

Comment: if use canvas to draw each shape, you can recording their position and area holding on, when motion down, you can use x-axis and y-axis to determinate which shape hold this point then highlight it.

Comment: what if only 1 image, that is this big image? i cannot get which part is clicked

Answer (score 0):

set implements OnTouchListener  for your class add the unimplement method then put all your image view in array and set setOnTouchListener

```
ImageView[] image = new ImageView[9];//for exapmle 9
image[i].setOnTouchListener(this);


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    boolean eventConsumed = true;
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        for (int i=0;i<=8;i++)//change the loop size to image array size
        {
            if (v == image[i]) {
                point=i;
                // here i'm getting which image i have touched
                System.out.println(" image"+i+i+i+i+i+i+i+i+i+i+"is clicked");

                }
        }else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

       //here wright the condition for which image what color have to give
        }
```

Comment: Here is the problem, standard imageview was square. When I touch transparent area, it involve 2 imageviews, I cannot know which imageview is touched.

Comment: apologies please.. i cant't get u how 2 imageview involves ..?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the touched part by changing its color then maybe you should use a **selector** for each image.

selector.xml -> drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/colored_image"  
 android:state_pressed="true"/>  
<item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_image" >
</selector>
```

ImageView:

```
     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/change_city_small_down_ImageView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/changeCityRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/selector"
   </ImageView>
```

It works, I just used it by overlapping `imageviews`:

[image][image] [image]

Comment: I believe that there are many ways to do one this. This one is the simplest. Your imageviews are overlapping each other. I'm going to try something out and let you know it that fixes that.

Comment: the keyword is overlapping between 2 imageviews

Comment: not working because bottom imageview which block by top layer will not get the click callback

Comment: can you show me how it work? Base on your answer i only know the image will change when the imageview (topper layer) being click, what if I want to click bottom view which is same coordinate.

For example: the finger (your image)

Comment: Look, you got 29 small  images, right? You have placed together to make it look like a car? I know that the `imageview` is square and not in the shape of car parts but even if they are overlapping, they'll change color according to the area touched. 

You have to make 29x2 images.. 29 normal ones and 29 having some color. And 29 selectors. The size of this project will be huge though. **If** you only need them to display touches then try using Buttons with the background as your image.

Comment: So you mean when touch the overlapping area, 2 imageviews will change?

Comment: What I mean is when touch, 2 imageviews were overlapped. The touch will always change the top layer because bottom layer being overlapped by top layer.

Comment: For example, Imageview A is bottom and imageview B is top so I want to click imageview A but cannot because imageview B will response to the click.

Comment: Upload this application's .rar/.zip file on your dropbox and give me the down link. I'll see to it.

Comment: @AlanLai did you solve it? If no, use onTouchListener instead of onClickListener. :)